# Functionality of data-sly-test for given example in image

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

Please find the below snippet. Can any one explain above functionality for the data-sly-test. How it will work condition here for image??

```
<div class="spon-image-container col-12 col-md-4">
    <sly data-sly-test="${properties.fileReference}">
        <img class="spon-_image" src="${properties.fileReference}"/>
    </sly>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to mention here. The gist of the code snippet is, that the `<img>` tag will only be rendered if `{$properties.fileReference}` is not empty.

Be aware, there is no sanity check involved here. `data-sly-test` won't check if the referenced file exists etc.

So assume that `${properties.fileReference}` equals `/content/dam/myImage.png`. Then the resulting HTML would like this:

```
<div class="spon-image-container col-12 col-md-4">
    <img class="spon-_image" src="/content/dam/myImage.png"/>
</div>
```

On the other hand, if the `${properties.fileReference}` is empty (or null) you get the following HTML:

```
<div class="spon-image-container col-12 col-md-4">
</div>
```

Depending on your HTML/CSS/JS you might not want that to happen. So you could improve your code to include the `data-sly-test` statement in the `<div>` tag:

```
<div class="spon-image-container col-12 col-md-4" data-sly-test="${properties.fileReference}">
    <img class="spon-_image" src="${properties.fileReference}"/>
</div>
```

This way, the `<div>` is only rendered, if a `fileReference` is set. But even if you still want the `<div>` to appear, your code can be improved by removing the `<sly>` element and adding the `data-sly-test` to the `<img>` tag:

```
<div class="spon-image-container col-12 col-md-4">
    <img class="spon-_image" 
         src="${properties.fileReference}"
         data-sly-test="${properties.fileReference}"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [specification](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#225-test), `data-sly-test`:

> Keeps or removes the element depending on the attribute value.

For your case if `fileReferece` property evaluates to `true` (not null, not empty), it will render:

```
<div class="spon-image-container col-12 col-md-4">

        <img class="spon-_image" src="....."/>

</div>
```

*Note that the `sly` tag unwraps/removes itself, it's actually unnecessary here as the `data-sly-test` attribute could be moved to the `img`.*

If `fileReference` evaluates to `false`, it will render:

```
<div class="spon-image-container col-12 col-md-4">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It basically checks if the current resource properties(i.e component properties) contain fileRefernce then it will add an image tag.